How is this operation called and denoted?
$$\{(X_0,Y_0)\}\ast\{(X_1,Y_1)\} = \{(X_0,Y_0),(X_0,Y_1),(X_1,Y_0),(X_1,Y_1)\}.$$
How is the operation $\ast$ called? It is not Cartesian product but something similar.
If the operand sets of $\ast$ have more than one element, we take:
$$\{(X_{00},Y_{00}),\dots,(X_{0n},Y_{0n})\}\ast\{(X_{10},Y_{10}),\dots,(X_{1m},Y_{1m})\} =
\bigcup_{ij}\big(\{(X_{0i},Y_{0i})\}\ast\{(X_{1j},Y_{1j})\}\big).$$
This operation appears as a join-semilattice operation that allows to describe funcoids as free stars. Free stars are kinda dual filters:
Free stars on a poset $\mathfrak{Z}$ are sets $F$ not equal to $\mathscr{P}\mathfrak{Z}$
with $A,B\in\overline{F}\Leftrightarrow\exists Z\in\overline{F}:(Z\sqsupseteq A\wedge Z\sqsupseteq B)$
(for every $A,B\in\mathfrak{Z}$).
Remark. I marked this with general topology tag, because it is closely related with funcoids, an object from my general topology research.

This can be written as a cartesian product/union of cartesian products, right? The first one is just ${X_0,X_1}\times{Y_0,Y_1}$.
